# NPC Disappearance during Marriage Event

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I asked Onmund (from the college of Winterhold), to marry me. He was my follower. We were in Riften, and he left me at midnight to go to the temple of Mara. I arrived at the temple an hour later, and he never showed up. I stood there all day, and then I fast traveled out and back. The priest chewed me out for not showing up for the wedding. He has never shown back up either in Riften or at the college. I looked for his body just in case he died, but never found him around the city or in the hall of the dead. How do I get him back, or is he gone forever?

I have the PS3 version of the game with all of the downloadable content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though, I wrote an answer to it earlier, I believed that you were a PC user. I regret to inform you that this is not possible on consoles, and if you could not manually find him, you can say he is as good as gone.

Though this may fix it, bit it is highly unlikely:

1. Ask someone else to marry you
2. Go to the temple to start the ceremony
3. Check the NPCs who arrive at the wedding and talk to Orlon, if he is present (Or maybe his dead body will appear there).
4. Reject your current partner
5. Marry Orlon

I will reinstate that the above solution has about 9-10% chance of succeeding, but you can try it, can't you?

Or

You can reload a previous save, and ask him again, but this time you will need to follow him to the Temple of Mara (In short body guard him).

Comment: Did it work, or you reloaded a previous save?

Answer (score 0):

The marriage system is kinda messed up. Half the time you dont see entry and exit between the temple. Just ask him to marry, then wait for a day and a quarter. The quest should remind you to go to the wedding. Hopefully that guy will be there.